# How do you get the purple shark fin?

Tags: candy-box-2

I got it once but I reset and I forgot how to get it.

Answer (score 2):

Go to The pier and Jump into the sea. After you defeat seahorses, sharks will start coming. After some time you will see shark with colored fin. The first one is red, then green and lastly purple.

I did it in multiple attempts so I'm unsure if you can get all three in one go.

Comment: I have done that about 30 times but I guess time to hold me breath.